# data attribute isn't outputting anything

Tags: html, wordpress

For some reason the `data-mainsrc` attribute isn't outputting anything. I'm trying to get it to output the image url.

`<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'home-thumb' );$url = $thumb['0']; ?>`

Did I format the code incorrectly?

**Full code**

```
    <!-- Start the loop -->
    <?php $home_query = new WP_Query('post_type=projects');

    while($home_query->have_posts()) : $home_query->the_post(); ?>

    <article class="project">
        <img width="375" height="375" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/loading.gif" data-mainsrc="<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'home-thumb' );$url = $thumb['0']; ?>" class="attachment-home-thumb" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <div class="overlay">
                <a class="post-link expand" href="#" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>">+</a>
            </div>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

</div><!-- #projects-list -->
```

Comment: What does it give if you remove second parameter `home_thumb` from `wp_get_attachment_image_src` ?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner Still the same. No output.

Comment: What is it give if you `echo` it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not echoing anything, just storing in a variable, so this

```
data-mainsrc="<?php
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'home-thumb' );
$url = $thumb['0']; ?>"
```

probably ends up looking like this once it is evaluated by php

`data-mainsrc=""`

The functions that start with `get_`... only return a value, unlike the functions that start with `the_`... which `echo` it.

so how about this

```
<?php
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'home-thumb');
$url = $thumb['0']; 
?>

<img width="375" height="375" src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/loading.gif" data-mainsrc="<?php
 echo $url; ?>" class="attachment-home-thumb" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Forgot to echo. I'll accept your answer in 6 min.

Comment: word. and what you're doing makes sense; (using `get_` instead of `the_`) since you are doing something with the return value `$url=$thumb[0];` before using it